# Vue Axios - with bootstrapVue and vuex, still problem to upload file and text?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have vue SPA and I trying to upload some images and text. I try using postman to test my server code and it's work, but my client-side still error.
I think I'm still mistaken for handle req.file.

1. addImage.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <b-form-group label-cols-sm="3" description="image title" label="Title">
     <b-form-input v-model="newImage.title"></b-form-input>
  </b-form-group>

  <b-form-group label="my Image" label-for="file" label-cols-sm="2">
    <b-form-file id="file" v-model="newImage.image"></b-form-file>
  </b-form-group>

  <b-button variant="primary" class="pl-5 pr-5" @click.prevent="addImage">Save</b-button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newImage: {
        title: '',
        image: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addImage() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addProduct', this.newProduct);
    }
  },
};
```

2. store.js

```
actions: {
  addImage(context, newImage) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
      },
    };

    Axios
      .post(`${baseUrl}/product`, newImage, config)
      .then(({ newImage }) => {
        context.commit('ADD_IMAGE', newImage);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show your error code.

Comment: is this the actual code? because I see many differente variables names....

Comment: no, some I change for a simple

Comment: I try to `console.log(newImage)` upper **Axios** and I get the data, but `console.log(newImage)` below **Axios**  **.then**, the result is undefined

Comment: hi,
i'm not sure, but, could you try to remove the curly brackets on 

`.then((newImage)=> {})`

have you a demo on codepen or other service like this?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to upload an image you have to set the content type and create FormData, like this:

```
    let data = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files.item(i);
        data.append('images[' + i + ']', file, file.name);
    }

    const config = {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }

    return axios.post('/api/images', data, config)
```